# RSpec testing `rand` inside `rand`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, random, rspec

I have the following method in a game I am developing:

```
  def search
    if rand(5) == 0
      weapon = Weapon.offset(rand(Weapon.count)).first
      users_weapon = UsersWeapon.create(user_id: self.id, weapon_id: weapon.id, ammo: weapon.max_ammo)
      self.users_weapons << users_weapon
      { :success => 'true', :weapon => users_weapon }
    else
      { :success => 'false' }
    end
  end
```

As you can see, I have two `rand`'s there.
Now, when I am trying to test it with rspec, I want to test the following it:

```
context 'when searches location' do
  subject(:user) { FactoryGirl.create :User }
  before { FactoryGirl.create :knife }
  before { FactoryGirl.create :pistol }

  context 'when finds knife' do
    before { srand(2) }
    it { user.search[:weapon].weapon.name.should == 'Knife' }
  end

  context 'when finds pistol' do
    before { srand(3) }
    it { p user.search[:weapon][:name].should == 'Pistol' }
  end
```

No matter what I pass in `srand` here, it only works in one of two ways:
**a) returns `Pistol`

OR

b) returns nil.**

I want to stub these `rand`s independently. I don't want to seed just one `weapon` in each context cause I want to actually test random weapon selection. How can I perform it?

Comment: What assertions do you wish to make about your random weapon selection? I.e. what is it about their behaviour that you want to demonstrate, and potentially maintain? If you wish to assert something about the randomness itself, that is a different issue to wanting to assert something about what happens when each code path is exercised.

Answer (score 2):

use intention revealing name for your method, then mock that method instead of rand

```
def search
  if rand(5) == 0
    weapon = Weapon.find_random
    # ...

class Weapon
  # ...
  def self.find_random
    self.offset(rand(self.count)).first
```

Now you can easily mock `Weapon.find_random`

And if desired, easily change your implementation later on

```
class Weapon
  # ...
  def self.find_random
    # postgres
    self.order("RANDOM()").limit(1).first
    # mysql
    self.order("RAND()").limit(1).first
```

Answer (score 0):

almost all `rand()` are psuedo random generators, their randomness depends on the seed that you start them with, stop seeding with the same number instead use something like time(`srand(gettime())`) or something that changes everytime.

PS: `gettime()` should return an int, you'll have to make a wrapper for Ruby's what normal time function returns to convert it to an int